# How do I get Drupal to recognize my 404 page override?

Tags: 7, theming

I am using a custom 404 page. I also have a theme installed.

This is what I did:

1. I created a node 95761 which contains my 404 error page.
2. I set node/95761 to be my 404 error page I've created a template in my theme node--error.tpl.php
3. I cleared my cache after uploading node--error.tpl.php to the server.
4. I've verified that node--error.tpl.php exists on the server and has my custom code in my theme's templates folder.
5. I go to [mydomain]/pathThatDoesNotExist

Actual result: The contents of node/95761

Expected result: The modified version that is contained in node--error.tpl.php

I also tried node--95761.tpl.php and that doesn't override node/95761 either.

Any ideas why Drupal 7 is not picking up the override and how to fix it?

While we're at it, should the name of the template actually be node--error-404.tpl.php so that it doesn't override 403 or other non-404 errors?

Comment: is 95761 the node ID or a title? templates should be node--{NODE ID}.tpl.php at least in drupal 7. It is different in 6 and 5 - which version of Drupal are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Have you check this link http://example.com/admin/config/system/site-information.
Visit the above link in your site and set the 404 error page for your site.

Answer (score 0):

If you have assigned 95761 node id as you error page and its not picking your override.

I think you need to add these lines in your template.php file of your active theme.

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
if ($variables['node']->type != "") {
$variables['template_files'][] = "page-node-" . $variables['node']->type;
  }
}
```

Hope it will work for you!